# Radio button Label Change

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to change the radio button label from actual value to another value

```
<li th:each="radioValueType: ${type}"><input type="radio"
                                th:field="*{heads[0].type}" th:value="${radioValueType}" /> 
                                <label th:text="${radioValueType}"></label></li>
```

below is my model attribute

```
    @ModelAttribute("type")
    public ArrayList<Integer> getType(){
         ArrayList <Integer> type = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         type.add(1);
         type.add(5); 
         return type;
    }
```

but when I need to show it I need it to be for 1 as 'single' for 5 as 'group'. I am totally new to `thymeleaf`

Answer (score 0):

finally after 3 hours found the solution below is the code

```
<li th:each="radioValueType: ${type}"><input type="radio"
                            th:field="*{heads[0].type}" th:value="${radioValueType}" /> 
                            <label th:text="( (${radioValueType} == 1)? 'Single' : 'Group')"></label></li>
```

in case if anyone got in to the same trouble